# Issue with merging polygons in R - Heavy Geojson file

Tags: r, union, polygon, geojson

I have a pretty heavy geojson file extracted from coral allen atlas. This file is composef of a multitude of polygons with an assign class. I am currently facing an issue while merging polygons of the same class using R. My goal is to reduce data size by merging polygons of the same class.
I am pretty new to handling geospatial data on R so my understanding is quite limited at the moment.

import the data:

```
geopath<-choose.dir(getwd())
geofilesnames<-list.files(geopath,pattern=".geojson",recursive=T)
geopath<-str_replace_all(geopath,"\\\\","/")
geofiles<-paste(geopath,geofilesnames,sep="/")
for (i in 1:length(geofiles)){
  # assign(strsplit(geofilesnames[2],"/")[[1]][2],geojsonio::geojson_read(geofiles[2],what="sp"))
  if (str_detect(geofilesnames[i],"boundary")){
    boundary<-
      bound<-geojsonio::geojson_read(geofiles[i],what="sp")
  }
  else if (str_detect(geofilesnames[i],"benthic")){
    benthic<-
      geojsonio::geojson_read(geofiles[i],what="sp",parse=T)
  }
  else if (str_detect(geofilesnames[i],"geomorphic")){
    geomorphic<-
      geojsonio::geojson_read(geofiles[i],what="sp",parse=T)
  }
}
```

Transform the data:

```
geomorphic_sf <- st_as_sf(geomorphic)
```

This line of code is taking ages and crash R

```
merged_sf <- geomorphic_sf %>% group_by(class) %>% mutate(geometry=st_combine(geometry))
```

I expect to have a sf file with polygon of the same class merged to reduce the size of my data.

The idea is to then be to plot the polygons and navigate smoothly :
merged_spdf <- as(merged_sf, "Spatial")

```
geomorphic$class<-as.factor(geomorphic$class)
n_classes <- length(levels(geomorphic$class)) # Assuming 'class' is the column name
palette <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n_classes,"Set3")
test_colors<-palette[geomorphic$class]
bounds<-sp::bbox(boundary)

#Map is really long to load if polygons are not union prior
leaflet(df) %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>% 
  addPolygons(data=boundary,label="Extrapolation scale from Coral Allen Atlas",color="grey",labelOptions=labelOptions(noHide = TRUE,textOnly=TRUE,direction = "auto",style=list('color'="grey",'font-size'="12px"))) %>% 
  fitBounds(lng1 = bounds[1,1],lat1=bounds[2,1],lng2 = bounds[1,2],lat2 = bounds[2,2]) %>%
  addPolygons(data=merged_spdf,color=palette) %>% 
  addLegend(position = "topright",colors=palette,labels=unique(geomorphic$class),opacity=0.5,title="Legend")
```

I'm pretty new to stackoverflow too so I'm not sure what's the appriopriate way to share with you this heavy folder (606Mo) to have a reproducible example in the meantime here is a Wetransferlink valid for 7 days: we.tl/t-q1LlPhvHcg .

Comment: Weclome to SO! Your import block ends with a list of filenames and the transform block continues from converting something (`geomorphic`) to `sf`, but what's happening between those operations? What's `geomorphic` ? Do you load and combine multiple files?  Though you most likely don't want `group_by(class)  %>% mutate(geometry=st_combine(geometry))`,  it returns the same number of rows as in input, perhaps just replace it with `group_by(class) %>% summarise()`

Comment: Thank you Margus for your time, I edited my question to include data importation. In the meantime I tried your approach and the end result is exactly the same, the executed line is indefiniely running until it crashes R.